# Find all solutions to the system $x \equiv 1 \pmod 4, x \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, and $x \equiv 5 \pmod 7$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

> Find all solutions to the congruences  $x \equiv 1 \pmod 4, x \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, and $x \equiv 5 \pmod 7$.

I got $M =m_1 * m_2 * m_3 = 4*3*7 = 84$

$M_1 = 21, M_2 = 28, M_3 = 12$

So I get $x = 21*u + 28*v + 12*w$

Now I don't know how to get $u, v$, and $w$. I know that I am supposed to use Chinese Remainder Theorem and Euler's algorithm but I don't know how to use them here. Can someone please help me. Or suggest me something easier.

Comment: Just apply extended euclidean algorithm to two of the congruences, then to the result apply the third.

Comment: Do you know, Pratyush, what $u,v,w$ stand for? how they are defined? No good "knowing" a formula, if you don't know what the letters mean. Also, when you write "Euler", chances are you mean "Euclid".

Comment: @GerryMyerson I do know what they mean.

Comment: @RushabhMehta so would I first solve x = 21u + 28v and then solve for w later?

Comment: Good. So, tell us, Pratyush: what do they mean?

Comment: You can always answer these by guess and check: First find a solution to the system $x \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ and $x \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$.  The solution will be unique mod $12$ due to CRT.  You need only check $0, 3, 6, 9$, since $x \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$.  Then take your solution, call it $x \equiv a \pmod{12}$, and find a common solution to $x \equiv a \pmod{12}$ and $x \equiv 5 \pmod{7}$ the same way.

Answer (score 2):

By CRT $\, x\, \equiv\,  1\cdot 21\,(\color{#c00}{21^{-1}}\!\bmod 4) + 0\cdot 28\,(28^{-1}\!\bmod 3) + 5\cdot12\,\color{#0a0}{(12^{-1}}\!\bmod 7)\ \ \pmod{84}$

$\quad  \bmod 4\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{21^{-1}}\equiv 1^{-1}\equiv \color{#c00}1$

$\quad  \bmod 7\!:\,\ \color{#0a0}{12^{-1}}\equiv (-2)^{-1}\equiv 1/(-2)\equiv 8/(-2)\equiv -4\equiv\color{#0a0}{ 3}$

Therefore $\ x\,\equiv\,  1\cdot 21\cdot\color{#c00} 1\, +\, 0\, +\, 5\cdot 12\cdot\color{#0a0} 3\equiv 201\equiv 33\pmod{84}.\ \ $  Aternative below.

---

$\!\bmod 3\!:\,\ x\equiv 0\iff  x = 3j$

$\!\bmod 7\!:\,\ x = 3j \equiv 5 \equiv 12\iff j \equiv 4\iff x = 3(4+7k) = 12+21k$

$\!\bmod 4\!:\,\ 1\equiv x = 12+21k\equiv k\iff x = 12+21(1+4n) = 33+84n$

Answer (score 0):

We have $x\equiv 0 \pmod 3.$

Since $\gcd(3,4)=1,$  the set $\{0+3n:1\leq n\leq 4\}$ is a complete residue system modulo $4.$ So just one member $(0+3\cdot 3=9)$ is congruent to $1$ mod $4.$ So $x\equiv 9 \pmod {3\cdot 4}.$

Since $\gcd(3\cdot 4,7)=1$ the set $\{9+12m: 1\leq m\leq 7\}$ is a complete residue system modulo $7.$ So just one member $(9+12\cdot 2=33)$ is congruent to $5$ mod $7.$ So $x\equiv 33 \pmod {3\cdot 4\cdot 7}.$